# Как создать проект с QtWebEngine?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Да, вопрос глупый наверное.... Но как?

Установил open source версию со след. компонентами:

```
Qt:
Qt 5.9 .6: 
  MinGW 5.3 .0 32 bit
  msvc2017 64 - bit
  Sources
  Qt Charts
  Qt Data Visualization
  Qt Purchasing
  Qt Virtual Keyboard
  Qt WebEngine
  Qt Network Auth(TP)
  Qt Remote Objects(TP)
  Qt Speech(TP)
  Qt Script
Tools: 
  Qt Creator 4.7 .1
  Qt Creator 4.7 .1 CDB Debugger Support
  MinGW 5.3 .0
  MinGW 7.3 .0 64 bit
```

Создаю любой проект (как widget, так и mainwindow). В итоге никак подключить WebEngine не выходит. При попытке подключения через `#include` файлы с нужным именем просто не находятся (в выпадающем списке их нет, а компилятор выдаёт соответствующую ошибку).
Хотя при этом в папке msvc WebEngine есть....

Comment: Добавили в проект `QT += webengine`?

Comment: Так тоже не работает

Comment: @Михаил, `qmake` после этого сделать не забыл?

Comment: Для компиляции используешь WinGW или msvc2017?